# Django run thread/task with database access allways paralell to webserver

Tags: python, django

I want to build a Mqtt Client, which stores some data in my django database.
This client should always run, when the webserver is running.

What is the best way to run a thread with database access (django models) paralle to the webserver?

If read about the django background task model, but I am not sure if its a good way.

Answer (score 1):

[Celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/) is the most common solution for this. You can also create a custom [admin command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/custom-management-commands/) and execute it using cron or something similar.